# Converting R code to python - matrix manipulation and indexing error

Tags: python, r, matrix

I have R code that, as part of an algorithm for matrix imputation, does the following initialization:

```
myfunc <- function(x, y, l1 = 1.0, l2 = 1.0, l3 = 1.0, r = 180, 
                      thresh = 1e-05, maxit = 100, penalty = 'all'){
  x_size = dim(x)
  m = x_size[1] #x of x
  n = x_size[2] #y of x
  t = x_size[3] #z of x
  
  xnas = is.nan(x) # the nan mask
  xfill = x
  
  U = list()
  V = list()
  Dsq = list()
  Impute = list()
  
  # initialize U, V, Dsq
  for (time in 1:t){
    u = matrix(rnorm(m*r),m,r)
    v = matrix(rnorm(n*r),n,r)
    U[[time]] = svd(u)$u
    V[[time]] = svd(v)$u
    Dsq[[time]] = rep(1,r)
    Impute[[time]] = U[[time]]%*%(rep(1,r)*t(V[[time]])) 
  }
#rest of the code
```

The input to `myfunc` is supposed to be two 200x300x150 tensors `x` and `y`, with `x` having many NaN values and `y` not having any NaN values.

I have tried to convert this to Python3 in the following way:

```
def myfunc(x, y, l1=1.0, l2=1.0, l3=1.0, r=180, thresh=1e-05, maxit=100, penalty='all'):
    x_size = np.array(x.shape) 
    m, n, t = x_size

    xnas = np.isnan(x)  # the nan mask
    xfill = np.copy(x)

    U = []
    V = []
    Dsq = []
    Impute = []

    # Initialize U, V, Dsq
    for time in range(t):
        print(time)
        u = np.random.randn(m, r)
        print(u.shape)
        v = np.random.randn(n, r)
        U.append(np.linalg.svd(u)[0])
        V.append(np.linalg.svd(v)[0])
        print(V[time].shape)
        Dsq.append(np.ones(r))
        #print((np.ones(r,1) * V[time].T).shape)
        Impute.append(U[time] @ (np.ones(r) * V[time].T))

#rest of the code down below
```

However, while executing this code, I get the error

```
**35**     Impute.append(U[time] @ (np.ones(r) * V[time].T))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (180,) (300,300) ``
```

where the main problem seems to be in the multiplication `np.ones(r) * V[time].T)`

I suspect that the error is the result of strange indexing going on with `V[[time]] = svd(v)$u` and `V.append(np.linalg.svd(v)[0])` being different in R and Python respectively. **I'm completely new to R**, so what would be the correct indexing for the Pythonic version of the code?